# Is there any mysql spatial gui manager that supports spatial data manipulation?

Tags: mysql, user-interface, geospatial, spatial

Is there any gui manager for mysql that supports spatial data manipulation, i use sqlyog but they don't have support for spatial data from the gui, although I can send any command to the server. But I would like to know if there is (somehow) some support for this kind of data from the gui manager or some addons to them.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think MySQL is the right solution for spatial data. If you look at the documentation most of the spatial methods are unimplemented. I think you would do much better with PostGIS or SpatialLite.

Comment: Please note the date on this post. The latest MySQL does have proper spatial functionality